# Inheriting a base class using vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

i am beginner and came across a code when i couldn't understand .anyone kindly explain below code in which  base class is derived using vector

```
class base{

public:
.
.
private :
.
.};

class derived :public vector<base *>
{

public:
};
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It isn't clear *what* exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Which part confuses you in particular? The `vector<base *>`? The class isn't derived from `base`, it inherits a `vector<base *>`.

Comment: Are you asking what the syntax means? Or why anyone in their right mind would inherit from a non-polymorphic class?

Comment: class derived :public vector<base *> i couldnt understand why they are inheriting using vector simply class derived :public base is enough right.explain both syntax and reason for inherting using vector<base *>

Comment: @user2365835 `vector<base*>` is not the same as `base*. You should ask the person who wrote the code why they did it. `derived` **is not** inheriting from `base`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks .Pls expalin use of above syntax

Comment: No, please study some basic C++. This is trivial stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vector** is **template** container defined in the STL header `<vector>` and a part of namespace `std` . Simply put, it acts like an array whose size can be changed just by adding a new element to it.

Just like you store objects of some **datatype** in an array (for eg. int, char, or any other type of object etc.), you can create a vector to store objects.

In your case `vector<base*>` is a **class** to hold pointers to objects of datatype **base**. since its a class, **public**ly inheriting a derived class from `vector<base*>` means that the derived class will have all the member variables and functions from `vector<base*>` and can have something extra (or even improvements) in addition to these.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is a [class template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template). This means that `std::vector<base*>` is a class by itself - it is a container of `base*` objects. Going to the definition of `derived`, you will see that `derived` is a class inheriting from the parent class `std::vector<base*>`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the class `base` is defined for members of a vector; then, the class template `vector` is used, which is most likely taken from the [C++ Standard Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/). Finally, a class `derived` is defined, which inherits from `vector<base*>`. This means that `derived` behaves basically the same as a vector of pointers to `base`, but perhaps adds or changes some properties. This cannot be told without actually inspecting the implemenatation of `derived`.

Comment: _"which is most likely taken from the STL."_ For modern compilers I doubt that seriously.

Comment: What do you mean by this? It is not really clear from the code where `vector` comes from; I don't really get the point of your comment.

Comment: The point is that is it most likely straight out of the C++ standard library. One would have to go through many loops to get the STL and I doubt OP is capable of doing that.

Comment: @Codor The STL is a very old implementation for the original c++ standard container proposals. Today we have the c++ standard library, what you probably meant.

Comment: I believed these were the same things; thanks for clarification!

Comment: Using derived class can we modify value of base class data members as we do using vector for primitive data types ( insert or remove values to vector ?